# Receving Error "'Migrations'-- invalid sender" during deployment to BSC mainnet

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, bsc

I have tried each of the suggestions mentioned in [the official issue pointing to this problem](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3936) to no prevail in BSC MainNet.
I have had success in BSC TestNet as well as Ropsten TestNet.
However, the issue resurfaces when attempting to execute `rm -rf node_modules; npm install; truffle deploy --network bsc` with the `truffle-config.js` pointing its `providerOrUrl` to `https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org` (I have also attempted pointing `providerOrUrl` to `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`).

For reference I am using my metamask wallet which is configured for the binance smart chain network.
I have also attempted to use several different versions of the `HDWalletProvider`.

> `1.2.2` - [suggested by @jerrkill](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3936#issuecomment-804668882)

> `1.2.3` - [suggested by @eggplantzzz](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3936#issuecomment-810359373)

> `1.0.18`, `1.2.1`, `1.2.6`, `1.3.1` - by natural experimentation

As [suggested by @nehal-backspace](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3936#issuecomment-835893271), I have also attempted to change `truffle-config`'s `const HDWalletProvider` from

> `const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');`

to

> `const HDWalletProvider =  require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');`

However, for each of the versions mentioned above, truffle was unable to fetch the package.

The above was reported while currently running Truffle version `5.3.1`.

Upon upgrading to Truffle version `5.3.5` I can verify that the issue persists with `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` set to `1.3.1` as well as `1.2.2`

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Which version of truffle are you using? What are your HDWalletProvider version and dependencies? I'd guess that the repo is somehow broken while trying with all those tests. The latest version truffle 5.3.5 and @truffle/hdwallet-provider 1.3.1  should have that bug fixed. I'd suggest to clean all dependencies and add what is really needed.

Comment: I can verify that upon changing my version from `5.3.1` to `5.3.5` that the issue persists with `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` set to `1.3.1` as well as `1.2.2`.

Comment: I'd suggest to contact truffle developers or open a new issue.